# iMac (early 2008 macOS 10.11) showing colourful lines during startup

Tags: macos, imac, graphics

I recently fixed an old iMac (early 2008) that was showing lines during boot and then going into white screen, I installed Ubuntu Server first and the problem seemed to have gone away, then i tried installing Debian but it broke it so I reinstalled it with Ubuntu Desktop. The problem seemed to be gone, so then I reinstalled it with OS X 10.9 and updated it up to 10.10 and then 10.11, it ran ok, even supporting Minecraft OptiFine 1.9. Then after shutting it down normally, it started showing lines (sometimes CYMK, sometimes RGB, sometimes black and cyan) again as if I hadn’t done anything. Help?
[image]
UPDATE: It seems to work perfectly when i hold the escape key during startup (but not when i don't), im not sure whats going on...? Doesn’t Work anymore, ig I’ll have to turn it into parts

Comment: First test, grab a screenshot, take a photo. Compare the two on another machine. If it shows on the photo but not the screenshot, it's a hardware fail. Post both to here.

Comment: I can’t take a screenshot because it goes into white screen and isn’t booting to macOS. But I have attached a photo.

Comment: Also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/196870/119271 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/281951/119271 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244293/my-mac-has-weird-lines-when-booting/244302#244302

Comment: Holding `Esc` is not an [Apple Startup Key](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) function.  This is bad hardware - nothing in software is going to fix this.